# how to create a zip file of the cd in bash script

Tags: bash, terminal, zip

i want to create the zip file of the current working directory in bash script. AND Redirect the stdout of zip command to a file called zip-output.txt.

i have a current workind directory called "music" and my script populates it with a lot of content. thus after it is populated i want to convert it to "music.zip" . but the contents of the "music" directory shouldn't be altered or zipped.

```
/Users/xyz/Downloads/music
```

this is the path to the cd "music" if need be and the file "zip-output.txt" could be created at the path "/Users/xyz/Downloads"

ik this is easy but i am new. please guide me

Comment: If you don't want to zip the contents of the directory, what *do* you want to include?

Comment: "_i want to create the zip file of the current working directory_" and "_i have a current workind directory called "music"_" and "_the contents of the "music" directory shouldn't be [...] zipped_" seems like an impossible task. How can all of those be combined?

Comment: i want. to zip the music file that contains the sub files. i do not want to zip the sub files individually

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
zip -r music.zip music/ | tee zip-output.txt
```